# Yii 1 command doesn't work with Yii mailer or simple PHP mail

Tags: php, yii

Yii 1 console command doesn't work with Yii mailer or simple PHP mail. I'm working on windows, but all is well when I go to frontend and test YiiMailer there.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was for yii2 sorry. It will be a pathing issue, it is a known bug with console apps in yii1 mail. See the below:

> Note
>
> In console apps, alias 'webroot' may not be the same as in web apps.
>   See [this yii issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1267). Best workaround is to set alias you need directly
>   in config/console.php, e.g.:
>
> Yii::setPathOfAlias('webroot.images.mail',
>   '/path/to/your/images/mail/dir');
>
> Yet another solution is to override protected/yiic.php and set
>   'webroot' alias there (see example files).

Taken from [**this page**](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/#hh4).

Other then that you might need to supply some additional code for me to delve deeper.